# View topological heads in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I like to check for any outstanding topological heads (`hg heads -t`), that might need merging, before I start new work. I don't see a way to do that in TortoiseHg using revsets. I don't filter often enough to become a revset poweruser, and they scare me.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) in TortoiseHg.  To check for unmerged heads, I typically do something like this:

1. Switch to the `Revision Details` view
2. Turn on the `Filter Toolbar`
3. Enter the following filter: `heads(all()) and not closed()`

Comment: And at the command line: hg log -r "heads(all()) and not closed()"